# check and uncheck checkbox according to db value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Hi i am working on check and uncheck the checkbox according to the value from db. One of the field in database is boolean. I want checkbox to be checked if value in db is 1 and unchecked if value in db is 0. My data are fetched from db in json but i am unable to check and uncheck checkbox according to value in db.

My code:

### jquery

```
 var alllist = "";
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/onload_todo'; ?>",
             dataType: "json",
            data: {

            },

            beforeSend: function()
            {

            },
            success: function(data)
            {
             var list_len = data.length;
             for(var i=0;i<list_len;i++)
             {
                  var imp_status = data[i].important;
                  var task_status = data[i].completion;   //it fetched data 0 or 1 for checkbox
                  alert(task_status);
                  alllist = '<li class="list-group-item"><span style="font-size:10px;color:#aaa;">'+ data[i].dates +'</span><br><input type="checkbox" class="taskToggle"><span>'+
                            data[i].list + '</span><span class="pull-right"><span class="'+ data[i].id +'"></span>' +
                            '<i class="icon-pencil" style="color:#f8a326"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                            '<i class="icon-remove" style="color:#f34541;cursor:pointer" id="del_list" title="Delete"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                            '<span class="'+ data[i].important +'"></span><i class="a" style="color:#00acec;cursor:pointer" title="Mark as important" id="imp"></i></span></li>';
             $("#inlist").append(alllist);
             if(imp_status == "0")
                 {
                    $(".a").attr("class","icon-bookmark-empty");
                 }
                  if(imp_status == "1")
                 {
                    $(".a").attr("class","icon-bookmark");
                 }

                 if(task_status == "1")  //to check for value and check the checkbox. Its not working.
                 {
                    $("input.taskToggle").prop('checked', true);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   $("input.taskToggle").prop('checked', false);
                 }
             }

            }
        });
```

This is the code i have done. It checked all the checkbox with both value 0 and 1 that is from database. Dont know why it is not checking if else.. statement. Please help me.

problem in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9w67rqdc/3/
 There is alert of completion object of json as 1 and 0. if 1 is alerted means it should check the checkbox as i had mention if(task_status == "1") then check the box but all checkbox even with task_status == "0" is also checked. Whats wrong here actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think start with

```
if(imp_status == "1")
```

OR

```
if(imp_status == 1)
```

As php gives issues with 0 value

Comment: check and uncheck is related with .taskToggle actually. I tried removing "" but it didnot worked

Comment: Use ALERT `alert(imp_status)` before `if(imp_status == "0")` What u r getting?

Comment: It is giving 0 or 1. That is according to db value.

Comment: So in alert() u get proper value ?

Comment: Type this code 
              `          
                 if(imp_status == "0")
                 {
                    alert("in if");
                    $(".a").attr("class","icon-bookmark-empty");
                 }
                 else if(imp_status == "1")
                 {
                   alert("in if");
                    $(".a").attr("class","icon-bookmark");
                 }`

Comment: you are not reading my comments properly. Check and uncheck is related with task_status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62463/discussion-between-user254153-and-jquery-angry-bird).